# Splash Screen Image in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources, android-resolution

Is it necessary to resize images of the splash screen for different screen size or its ok to keep one image with the highest required resolution and add it to the *drawable* folder and use it as it is.

Also I have the same doubt for the clipArts that I am showing in my app. These clip arts are almost 3/4th of the screen size. Do i need to use one highest required resolution image. OR different sized images.

Please help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh please don't use a splash-screen. (just an opinion, I know, but afaik in one of the "Android Design in action" episodes splash screens are bashed as well)

Comment: [The recommendation](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html) from Google is _"Since Android runs in devices with a wide variety of screen densities, you should always provide your bitmap resources tailored to each of the generalized density buckets: low, medium, high and extra-high density. This will help you achieve good graphical quality and performance on all screen densities."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maintain different resolutions for different devices.

You want an image that will fill the entire screen? There are over 50 supported android phones, each with a different resolution. You can't expect to create an image of the exact size of each phone. Instead, you'll probably need to come up with a few different versions and then allow it to stretch to fill the full screen.

hdpi, ldpi, mdpi refers the density of pixels on the screen, not the screen size. Thus, one mdpi screen might be 320x480 while another might be 480x854.

[Supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) has lots of good information dealing with the different screen sizes and densities. [Icon design](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html) has specific suggestions for pixels sizes for different icons at the different screen densities.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a quality view you have to resize for all of the resolutions. Just take hdpi example that have multiple size resolutions and variate width. For that if you have the highest resolution for sure you will not have the same ratio and the image will be stretch. So I sugest you to make resources for all resolutions.